# Web applications MongoDB database structure

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have simple web application in Spring boot to creating a CV profile.
Profile is my primary model and I want to add another section Education that I can easly add, remove and update new fields of that section.

```
Profile.class

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "profiles")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Education> education;
}

Education.class

@Data
public class Profile {

    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
    private String description;

}
```

Theres no problem with add new education object ,but I have a problem with finding Education object to remove or update in list.

Is there a better way to create sub-document in MongoDB that I can easly  find some object and remove or update them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all can't do CRUD operations on `Education` entity without having its unique identifier. Secondly CRUD operations of `Education` entity (e.g. through REST) are done always in the context of the parent `Profile` entity. It means that e.g. update of the `Education` entity are actually updates of the `Profile` document if you model both as one collection.

Pseudo code for removal of education would look like:

```
removeEducation(profileId, eductionId) { // you need profileId here
    Profile profile = findProfile(profileId)
    profile.removeEducationById(eductionId) // updates the document
    saveProfile(profile)
}
```

It would be different if you modeled both entities as separate collections.